# Is there a way to Find & Replace a cell reference value in Excel 2010? VBA?

Tags: vba, replace

I have an Excel worksheet that contains a bunch of charts created from data pulled from another worksheet in the workbook. At the beginning of each month, when I add last month's data to the data worksheet, I shift everything over one column such that what *was* last month is now in column O, and what is *now* last month is always in column P. Problem is, I want the worksheet with the charts to always chart the current "last month" (always column P), but it's "smart" enough to re-configure the charts to keep charting the data it had been charting (i.e., the previous "last month"), which is now in column O.

Specifically, I'd like to change (for example)
`=SERIES("Visits",Data!$D$4:$O$4,Data!$D$4:$O$4,1)`
to
`=SERIES("Visits",Data!$D$4:$P$4,Data!$D$4:$P$4,1)`

Find & Replace doesn't seem capable of doing that. Is it possible with VBA? (I'm a total VBA noob.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is how you're "shifting" the data.  If you are deleting/inserting or moving data then Excel will update its references.  You could copy the data and paste it 1 column to the left, and then paste your current 'last month' data into column P.

In short, copying and pasting will not force Excel to update its pointers, moving/deleting/inserting will.

If this isn't an option look into the OFFSET function - if you can incorporate that into the data-range you might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Pete, good suggestions, and I think you're right -- it's the way we're shifting data in the spreadsheet that's causing the problem. I tried OFFSET, and couldn't get it to work since the data was on a different sheet [DATA!OFFSET(...) just didn't work]. What **did** work though was a named range. At least I think it worked. I have more testing to do, but it's after midnight and that's all I can do today. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using dynamic ranges which automatically extend your range as data is added, see [this example from Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html) for a start

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to perform find-replace on series formulas, but you can write VBA code to do it. I've written a tutorial about this, [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](http://peltiertech.com/change-series-formula-improved-routines/). I show a number of VBA routines, but the simplest is below.

The following sub checks for an active chart, then prompts the user for 'change what' and 'to what' strings, $O$ and $P$ in your case, and then changes all series formulas in the active chart.

```
Sub ChangeSeriesFormula()
    ''' Just do active chart
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
        '' There is no active chart
        MsgBox "Please select a chart and try again.", vbExclamation, _
            "No Chart Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim OldString As String, NewString As String, strTemp As String
    Dim mySrs As Series

    OldString = InputBox("Enter the string to be replaced:", "Enter old string")

    If Len(OldString) > 1 Then
        NewString= InputBox("Enter the string to replace " & """" _
            & OldString & """:", "Enter new string")
        '' Loop through all series
        For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            strTemp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(mySrs.Formula, _
                OldString, NewString)
            mySrs.Formula = strTemp
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to be replaced.", vbInformation, "Nothing Entered"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can extract the core of this routine and call it from other routines that cycle through all charts on a worksheet, all charts in a workbook, etc.